# Process.Start not working with UNC path to Filezilla

Tags: c#, azure, command-line, file-permissions, unc

This code used to work below on the C Drive where it was installed.  We moved it to a UNC path \share and now it doesnt seem to reload the config file.  There are no errors, and Filezilla works fine as I can connect and transfer files over on this UNC Share, but from code I cant get this to actually do what it's suppose to anymore.  Do I need to do anything special credential wise?  My user account for the app pool of the site is the same as the share.

```
Process.Start("CMD.exe", "/C \"\\filezilla\\FileZilla Server.exe\" /reload-config");
```

**Update**

I ran this line from the command prompt on the actual computer and it does what it's suppose to.

Another Update

```
var path = string.Format("/C \"{0}FileZilla Server.exe\" /reload-config", Config.Paths.FileZillaPath); // \\filezilla\
Process.Start("CMD.exe", path);
Logger.Debug("Path: " + path); // Path: /C "\\filezilla\FileZilla Server.exe" /reload-config
```

Answer (score 10):

Your first pair of backslashes in the UNC path aren't escaped properly and will result in a single backslash. Try

```
Process.Start("CMD.exe", "/C \"\\\\filezilla\\FileZilla Server.exe\" /reload-config");
```

You can see an example at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx)

> string g = "\\\\server\\share\\file.txt";   // \\server\share\file.txt
>
> string h = @"\\server\share\file.txt";      // \\server\share\file.txt

Comment: Is the new update right above?  The path spits out `/C "\\filezilla\FileZilla Server.exe" /reload-config`

Comment: Yes that looks to be correct. Is it still not running? If not, open a command window and run `CMD.exe /C "\\filezilla\FileZilla Server.exe" /reload-config` to see if you get any errors. (I believe you've done this already but just check the syntax matches that).

Answer (score 3):

I've done something similar but like this...

```
 Process reloadConfig = new Process();
 reloadConfig.StartInfo.FileName = @"\\MachineName\FileZilla Server\FileZilla Server.exe\";
 reloadConfig.StartInfo.Arguments = @"/reload-config";
 reloadConfig.Start();
```

and that works for me.